# Reinforcement Learning, Policy iteration terminal state issue

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The code of computing the state-value function $V^{\pi_{n}}$ is

```py
def compute_vpi(mdp, policy, gamma):
    """
    Computes V^pi(s) FOR ALL STATES under given policy.
    :param policy: a dict of currently chosen actions {s : a}
    :returns: a dict {state : V^pi(state) for all states}
    """
    all_states, n = mdp.get_all_states(), len(mdp.get_all_states())
    state_index = {s: i for i, s in enumerate(all_states)}
    a, b = np.zeros((n, n)), np.zeros(n)
    for i, state in enumerate(all_states):
        vs = [1] + [0] * (n-1)  # current line of state
        next_state = mdp.get_next_states(state, policy[state])
        b[i] = sum([mdp.get_transition_prob(state, policy[state], next_s) * 
                    mdp.get_reward(state, policy[state], next_s)
                    for next_s in next_state])
        for next_s in next_state:
            vs[state_index[next_s]]  = - mdp.get_transition_prob(state, policy[state], next_s)
        a[i] = vs
    return {state: v for v, state in zip(np.linalg.solve(a, b), all_states)}
```

And I found that some states are the terminal state that if agent steps into these states, current episode ends. But in the `policy`, I don't konw how to set actions, since in `mdp`, there are no possible actions in the terminal state.

How can I taking into consideration the terminal state when computing the state-value function $V^{\pi_{n}}$  at each iteration?

Comment: I suspect the down vote is for the code, as Cross Validated likes to have questions closer to stats and maths theory. You may find this sort of practical "how do I address code issue in machine learning" question works better in Data Science or Stack Overflow. Regarding the code, it would be a good idea to explain what actually goes wrong - does the code run but give incorrect results, or is there an error?

Comment: To me, this looks like a practical coding concern in Python, and not really to do with reinforcement learning (although understanding RL allows reader to understand the purpose of the code).

Comment: @NeilSlater, Thank you, the question is a practical coding concern of policy iteration. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @NeilSlater, hi, I answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer my question

Recall that $V^{\pi}$ satisfies the following linear equation:
$$V^{\pi}(s) = \sum_{s'} P(s,\pi(s),s')[ R(s,\pi(s),s') + \gamma V^{\pi}(s')]$$

the code can be

```py
def compute_vpi(mdp, policy, gamma, num_iter=1000, min_difference=1e-5):
    """
    Computes V^pi(s) FOR ALL STATES under given policy.
    :param policy: a dict of currently chosen actions {s : a}
    :returns: a dict {state : V^pi(state) for all states}
    """
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    index_s = {i: s for i, s in enumerate(mdp.get_all_states())}
    s_index = {s: i for i, s in enumerate(mdp.get_all_states())}

    ns = len(mdp.get_all_states())
    a, b = np.zeros((ns, ns)), np.zeros(ns)
    for i in range(ns):
        b_v = 0
        state = index_s[i]
        a[i][i] = 1 - mdp.get_transition_prob(state, policy[state], state) * gamma
        for s_prime in mdp.get_next_states(state, policy[state]):
            if s_prime == state: continue
            a[i][s_index[s_prime]] = \
                -mdp.get_transition_prob(state, policy[state], s_prime) * gamma
            b_v += mdp.get_transition_prob(state, policy[state], s_prime) *\
                mdp.get_reward(state, policy[state], s_prime)
        b[i] = b_v

    solution = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
    return {index_s[i]: v for i, v in enumerate(solution)}
```

The best practice to solve the equation is to build a matrix a and b and loop in each state and each entry of the matrix a, and b to update corresponding values.

Comment: To me it was a bit tricky to see what should be in a matrix and b vector. I think it's worth noting that the aforementioned equation should be transformed such that all V is on the left side and constants (P * R) on the right side. Then unroll it into matrices.

Comment: @Lubiluk It is a working code for solving policy iteration via solving a linear equation. That is what I exactly did in the code by creating matrice `a` and `b`.